# Explain some httpClient properties

Tags: java, http, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

Can someone please explain the below properties used in HTTP clients and significance of each one?

1. defaultMaxPerRoute
2. maxTotalConnections
3. soTimeout
4. keepAlive
5. idleConnectionMonitorOn

Comment: The question is too broad and looks like a replacement for a tutorial website link. You will need to pick a specific problem before you ask, rather than ask to explain like paragraph-questions. Refer to SO question asking guidelines. Thank you.

Comment: @WhirlMind : Do you have any tutorial link for this ? That will do as well :) Actually i tried to find the detail of these props on web but unable to find any resource with proper explaination

Answer (score 0):

A quick search with site:apache.org gives the following results :

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html

https://etch.apache.org/documentation/howto-keepalive-filter.html

https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpConnectionParams.html

https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.html

And : 
http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management